# Faraday 0.9.1 breaks Balanced gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, balanced-payments, faraday

I cannot migrate because of this error and after hours of trying I cannot find a fix.

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `register_middleware' for #<Faraday::Connection:0x007fe658934bd0>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday.rb:99:in `method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced/client.rb:41:in `build_conn'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced/client.rb:30:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced.rb:29:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced.rb:29:in `configure'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced.rb:86:in `<module:Balanced>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
```

Anybody can offer some help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with using Faraday 0.9.1 with Balanced 0.8.1. Official details/progress here:
https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby/issues/173